# MySQL @rownum UPDATE correlativo en base a un parent_id

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Tengo el siguiente dilema, una tabla "personal_antecedente" la cual hereda de la tabla "personal" el idPersonal, contiene un campo "correlativo", el cual debe tener una suerte de autoincrementable en base al idPersonal.

Es decir, por cada registro en la tabla personal_antecedente el correlativo debe aumentar +1 desde el numero 1 y volver a empezar cuando cambie el idPersonal.

El autoincrementable ya funciona correctamente al agregar nuevos registros, el problema es que este correlativo fué implementado después de que la tabla había sido poblada, por lo que los registros antiguos quedaron con el campo correlativo en NULL.

Yo implementé un procedimiento almacenado para actualizar todos los registros de la tabla personal_antecedente, logrando dejar el correlativo correctamente.

Mi duda es cómo transformar este procedimiento almacenado a un sólo UPDATE que haga exactamente lo mismo.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `correlativo`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE a INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT idPersonal FROM personal;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO a;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET @rownum=0;
    UPDATE personal_antecedente
    SET correlativo = (@rownum:=@rownum+1)
    WHERE idPersonal = a
    ORDER BY idAntecedente;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Si alguien necesita actualizar un correlativo en base a un parent_id con un sólo update, esta sería la sintaxis en MySQL

```
set @row_number := 0;

UPDATE
    personal_antecedente pa    
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            @row_number:=CASE
                    WHEN @personal_id = tabla.idPersonal
                        THEN @row_number + 1
                    ELSE 1
                END AS num,
            @personal_id:= tabla.idPersonal idPersonal,
            tabla.idAntecedente
        FROM
        (
            SELECT idAntecedente, idPersonal
            FROM personal_antecedente
            ORDER BY idPersonal
        ) as tabla
        ORDER BY idPersonal) AS pa2 ON (pa2.idAntecedente = pa.idAntecedente)
SET
    pa.correlativo = pa2.num
```

Fuente: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Comment: Que bueno encontraste la respuesta, por favor no olvides que puedes marcar en dos días la respuesta como aceptada